# Converting web image url to Windows.Foundation.Uri to use on a secondary tile (JS, Windows 8)

Tags: javascript, url, windows-8, uri, windows-store-apps

I am trying to get my Windows 8 "Metro" application to work so that when i add a tile i can use an image dynamically got from the internet. I am aware i cannot set the Windows.UI.StartScreen.SecondaryTile uriLogo to a remote image uri.

At the moment I have the following code

```
var uriImage = "http://www.myURL.com/images/ffe8e8rq.jpg";
var uriLogo = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(uriImage);

...

var tile = new Windows.UI.StartScreen.SecondaryTile(Scenario1TileId,
            "Title text shown on the tile",
            "Name of the tile the user sees when searching for the tile",
            newTileActivationArguments,
            Windows.UI.StartScreen.TileOptions.showNameOnLogo,
            uriLogo);
```

The uriLogo is throwing a type exception and I know that I need to store the image from uriImage to a local file then reference that but could anyone give me advise where to start this from or an example i can reference from. After looking through Documentation I am still stuck where to even start this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have some code that does this, from [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/19/real-world-secondary-tiles-top-three-tips-for-working-with-secondary-tiles-in-windows-8-apps.aspx).  It's in C#, so you will have to translate into JavaScript.

```
/// <summary>
/// Copies an image from the internet (http protocol) locally to the AppData LocalFolder.  This is used by some methods 
/// (like the SecondaryTile constructor) that do not support referencing images over http but can reference them using 
/// the ms-appdata protocol.  
/// </summary>
/// <param name="internetUri">The path (URI) to the image on the internet</param>
/// <param name="uniqueName">A unique name for the local file</param>
/// <returns>Path to the image that has been copied locally</returns>
private async Task<Uri> GetLocalImageAsync(string internetUri, string uniqueName)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(internetUri))
     {
         return null;
     }

     using (var response = await HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(internetUri).GetResponseAsync())
     {
         using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
         {
             var desiredName = string.Format("{0}.jpg", uniqueName);
             var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(desiredName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

             using (var filestream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
             {
                 await stream.CopyToAsync(filestream);
                 return new Uri(string.Format("ms-appdata:///local/{0}.jpg", uniqueName), UriKind.Absolute);
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jennifer, ill let you know how i get along! :)

Comment: Any way you can provide a js version ,after trying i was unable to get anywhere unfortunately. Not advanced yet to be able to hack that into JS